# Styling a Checkbox on a TreeView

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I have a div containing a TreeView, like this:

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: -160px;" class="TreeView">
    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ImageSet="Simple" ShowLines="True" ShowCheckBoxes="All">
    </asp:TreeView>
</div>
```

If I have the following style:

```
#cpMainContent_TreeView1n0CheckBox {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 10px; 
}
```

My checkbox is displayed how I want it, but really I want all checkboxes in the TreeView to have the same style, I have tried:

```
.TreeView.input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 10px;
}
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use space character for getting child members. Try this if `TreeView` ID is `cpMainContent_TreeView1` in the browser:

```
#cpMainContent_TreeView1 input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 10px; 
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. Out of interest do you know if what I tried `.TreeView.input[type="checkbox"]` is invalid or does it do something I'm not expecting?

Comment: You are always welcome. `#` is used when we get it by ID and `.` is used when we get it by class.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, from your code i would say that you should write following CSS

```
.TreeView input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 10px;
}
```

Comment: do you possibly have some other CSS overriding this? Try using chrome developer tools to inspect the element and see if there is something overriding it

Comment: Sorry, I just adjusted my comment. It was because with Arshad's answer I didn't need the class in the div, so took it out. Of course, for your answer it needs the class there. Apologies.